# Using input in textarea to trigger a video event - javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I'm working on an HTML5 video logging and transcription application. The transcriptionist needs to be able to start and stop the video using a keyboard shortcut / accelerator rather than clicking a button. Is there a way for me to use javascript to do this without leaving the textarea box?

Thanks,
Norm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jLt39/). Shortcut for stopping/starting the video is 'alt + enter key'.

HTML:

```
<video src="http://v2v.cc/~j/theora_testsuite/320x240.ogg" controls id="video">
  Your browser does not support the <code>video</code> element.
</video>
<textarea></textarea>
```

Javascript (using jQuery):

```
$(function(e) {
    $('textarea').keydown(function(e) {
        // shortcut for stopping/starting the video
        // is alt + enter
        if (e.altKey && e.keyCode == 13) {
            toggleVideoPlay();
            return false;
        }
    });
});

function toggleVideoPlay() {
    var video = $('#video')[0];
    if (video.paused) {
        video.play();
    } else {
        video.pause()
    }
}​
```